# Prevent plot.gam from producing a figure

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

Say, I have a GAM that looks like this:

```
# Load library
library(mgcv)

# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Model for mpg
mpg.gam <- gam(mpg ~ s(hp) + s(wt), data = mtcars)
```

Now, I'd like to plot the GAM using `ggplot2`. So, I use `plot.gam` to produce all the information I need, like this:

```
foo <- plot(mpg.gam)
```

This also generates an unwanted figure. (Yes, I realise that I'm complaining that a plotting function plots something...) When using `visreg` in the same way, I'd simply specify `plot = FALSE` to suppress the figure, but `plot.gam` doesn't seem to have this option. My first thought was perhaps `invisible` would do the job (e.g., `invisible(foo <- plot(mpg.gam))`), but that didn't seem to work. Is there an easy way of doing this without outputting the unwanted figure to file?

Comment: In general, base `plot` will create a plot of whatever it's given. Any methods that let you turn plotting off are the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, so I finally figured it out 5 minutes after posting this. There is an option to select which term to plot (e.g., `select = 1` is the first term, `select = 2` is the second), although the default behaviour is to plot all terms. If, however, I use `select = 0` it doesn't plot anything and doesn't give an error, yet returns exactly the same information. Check it out:

```
# Load library
library(mgcv)

# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Model for mpg
mpg.gam <- gam(mpg ~ s(hp) + s(wt), data = mtcars)

# Produces figures for all terms
foo1 <- plot(mpg.gam)

# Doesn't produce figures
foo2 <- plot(mpg.gam, select = 0)

# Compare objects
identical(foo1, foo2)

[1] TRUE
```

Bonza!